# What is the fastest healing method?

Tags: dark-souls-2

What spell, or consumable item can give you health the fastest? In dark souls healing yourself in time means life or death. Sometimes you bring the estus flask to your lips and you are already dead. Is there something that can heal you quicker?

Comment: Are you referring to the entire animation or just the speed at which you regenerate health?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for "the fastest animation that can let me start regenerating health", then the animation for lifegems is **a bit** faster* than drinking estus flask, which is considerably faster than any healing spell. However, it regenerates quite slowly compared to nearly immediate restoration from Estus or Heal spells

If you're looking for "the largest amount of health I can recover in the shortest period of time", Estus wins

*: the time spent from initiating the animation (as Gamb says, you still can move during this, only at walking speed) to the item taking effect (health starts regenerating) is faster than Estus' animation. Not by a large margin, though

Comment: Though the answer is correct, there are a couple of points: You actually CAN move while crushing a lifegem (walk speed) and you can consume multiple Estus Flask uses on the same drinking animation by tapping the Estus button as much times as uses you want to consume.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that you can put down "Bountiful Sunlight" (the glowing orb that heals people standing next to it) ahead of time, and even fight while healing. The only problem is that your opponent can also regenerate while standing near, so you'll have to have a good weapon/technique for zoning them out of it. This is one of the best ways to heal while fighting, though.

Comment: @Gamb really? It's been some time since I last played DS2, I don't remember walking while activating lifegems. I'll correct the answer

Comment: @LucasLeblanc Bountiful Sunlight heals the enemy as well? I thought that was only the pyromancy Warmth?

Comment: @Ben Er, maybe. I get the two confused, since I don't use those spells hardly at all.

Comment: @LucasLeblanc just had a look at it, turns out you were just thinking of "Warmth". The "Bountiful Sunlight" miracle is a large AOE that casts a regenerative effect on any *friendlies* in the area. It doesn't affect enemies.

Comment: @Ben OK. I know that Warmth does what I think it does, but I wasn't sure if Bountiful Sunlight was the same thing for miracle users or not.